# Comparing Eigenvalues of Positive Semidefinite Matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

If $B\succeq A$, show that $\lambda_n(B)\ge\lambda_n(A)$, where $\lambda_n$ is the $n$th largest eigenvalue.

It is Theorem 6 in [this paper](http://www.math.ucsd.edu/~njw/Teaching/Math271C/Lecture_03.pdf) but the proof is only given as "by characterization." Do they mean the min/max characterization of eigenvalues,
$$\lambda_k=\min\max\frac{x^TAx}{x^Tx}$$
and if so, how is that applied?

Thanks.

Comment: Are $A$ and $B$ positive semidefinite? From your link the relation $\succeq$ seems to apply to any two square matrices of the same dimension, (e.g., $I \succeq -I$).

Comment: $A$ and $B$ are not necessarily positive definite.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$B\succeq A$ means that 
$$\tag{1} x^*Bx\geq x^*Ax \quad \text{for all $x$.}$$
Let $\lambda_i(A)$ be the $i$th largest eigenvalue of $A$. The Courant-Fischer theorem states that
$$\tag{2}
\lambda_i(A)=\max_{S:\;\dim S=i}\;\min_{x\in S\setminus\{0\}}\frac{x^*Ax}{x^*x}.
$$
Let $S'$ be a subspace of dimension $i$ for which the maximum in (2) is attained:
$$
\lambda_i(A)=\min_{x\in S'\setminus\{0\}}\frac{x^*Ax}{x^*x}.
$$
Then (1) gives
$$
\lambda_i(A)=\min_{x\in S'\setminus\{0\}}\frac{x^*Ax}{x^*x}\leq
\min_{x\in S'\setminus\{0\}}\frac{x^*Bx}{x^*x}
\leq
\max_{S:\;\dim S=i}\;\min_{x\in S\setminus\{0\}}\frac{x^*Bx}{x^*x}=\lambda_i(B).
$$