# Bound on the eigenvalues of PSD matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Given That A and B are two PSD ([positive semi-definite](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Positive-definite_matrix#Negative-definite.2C_semidefinite_and_indefinite_matrices)) real matrices and the following holds
$$
A \leq B 
$$
(meaning that $$ B-A $$ is also PSD)

can I bound the eigenvalues of A using the eigenvalues of B?

Thanks

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1225138/comparing-eigenvalues-of-positive-semidefinite-matrices/1225232#1225232

Comment: The matrices $A$ and $B$ do not need to be PSD, it's enough that they are Hermitian (or real symmetric).

Answer (score 0):

We know that the trace of a matrix is equal to the sum of its eigenvalues.  Further, since each entry in $A$ is no greater than the corresponding entry of $B$, it follows that tr($A)\le$tr($B)$. Thus, the sum of the eigenvalues of $A$ can be no greater than the sum of the eigenvalues of $B$, in other words, you could say 1) That, on average, the eigenvalues of $A$ must be less than or equal to the eigenvalues of $B$; 2)That the range of possible eigenvalues for $A$ are bounded above by tr$(B)$.

Comment: Thanks, but can I conclude that from A≤B as defined above, that each entry in A is no greater than the corresponding entry of B?